# Components in React

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code from the React documentation. Question:

Why do i have to use the formatDate function? Lets say i just want to use the raw date output from the new Date () function, why cant i just use it as props.date? does not seem to work.

```
function formatDate(date) {
  return date.toLocaleDateString();
}

function Avatar(props) {
  return (
    <img className="Avatar"
         src={props.user.avatarUrl}
         alt={props.user.name} />
  );
}

function UserInfo(props) {
  return (
    <div className="UserInfo">
      <Avatar user={props.user} />
      <div className="UserInfo-name">
        {props.user.name}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Comment(props) {
  return (
    <div className="Comment">
      <UserInfo user={props.author} />
      <div className="Comment-text">
        {props.text}
      </div>
      <div className="Comment-date">
        {formatDate(props.date)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const comment = {
  date: new Date(),
  text: 'I hope you enjoy learning React!',
  author: {
    name: 'Hello Kitty',
    avatarUrl: 'http://placekitten.com/g/64/64'
  }
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <Comment
    date={comment.date}
    text={comment.text}
    author={comment.author} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: "Does not seem to work" doesn't really tell us much. I'm guessing it's because `props.date` is an object or something which you can't just directly put into JSX. What kind of error message do you get when using the raw `props.date` value?

Comment: i am looking at this in the codepen.

Comment: https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/rrJNJY?editors=0010

Comment: line 32, when i remove the formatDate function and just put (props.date) on that line like the other elements, nothing displays

Comment: i meant that i write {props.date} in that line like the others

Comment: Yeah so if you look in the console for error messages (which you should do first and include in your questions) you can see the error "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Thu Oct 26 2017 13:40:02 GMT+1100 (AEDT))." because `props.date` is an object, not a string. You can't render objects in JSX, it has to be strings or a JSX element or an array of JSX elements.

Comment: The `formatDate()` function takes the object and turns it into a string, which is allowed to be embedded in JSX

Comment: Thanks a lot. My console log was showing different errors when i tried to look it up after you mentioned this. Your comments make perfect sense.